# onSaveInstanceState0 Doesn't survive Activity Death

Tags: android, android-studio, activity-lifecycle

im trying to override onSaveInstanceState in my activity

->the activity overrides onSaveInstanceState() to save an Int.

->the int is stored in a viewModel.

->onSaveInstanceState() gets called successfully

->its stored and restored on configuration changes but it Doesn't survive Activity death!!!!

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    var i =0
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    Log.i("TAGGY", "onSaveInstanceState")
     outState.putInt(Key_Index, QuizViewmodel.CurrentIndex)
}


 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val CurrentIndex = savedInstanceState?.getInt(Key_Index, 0) ?:0
    QuizViewmodel.CurrentIndex = CurrentIndex
    QstText = findViewById(R.id.Questiontext)
                                    }
```

Comment: Did you check that official document it may help u:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states

Comment: Also u could check thst video fo onSavedInstanceState but its content in Java not kotlin :
https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud855/lessons/79936377-aa69-45ae-a386-d865dcb36518/concepts/b70f337f-216e-4c81-bec4-62f53756cfb0

Comment: thank you, I checked the docs and still the problem persists

Comment: Try to change variable scope to be inside class & outside onCreate fn